# Am I interpreting this list comprehension correctly in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am still fairly new to python and still have some fumbles when reading list comprehensions. I tried translating two list comprehensions I saw in a tutorial into its elongated form. Did I translate correctly?

list comprehension 1

```
mytokens = [ word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens ]
```

translation 1

```
for word in mytokens:
    if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-":
        word.lemma_.lower().strip()
    else:
        word.lower_
```

list comprehension 2

```
mytokens = [ word for word in mytokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations ]
```

translation 2

```
for word in mytokens:
    if word not in stopwords and not in punctuations:
        yield word
```

for translation 2, I dont think "yield word" would be correct since its not a definition. I am guessing list comprehension 2 does the if statement and places the word back into the list mytokens so maybe it should be a .append?

Comment: Do your translations *do the same thing*? That should provide your answer.

Comment: I am not sure if they do the same thing hence the question!

Comment: So did you *test* them? What you've posted here isn't valid syntax on its own, and neither actually creates a list.

Comment: Oh i thought this would be simple for an experienced coder-- like reading a equation from a subject matter someone is familiar in. I didnt realize you need the variables in context to be able to figure out list comps. Sorry! p.s. if this isnt a list comprehension what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is right. You are looping correctly. However, you aren't adding the words to a list? Do you mean to be doing this?

So for the first one you could use

```
my_list = []
for word in mytokens:
    if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-":
        my_list.append(word.lemma_.lower().strip())
    else:
        my_list.append(word.lower_)
```

By adding them to a list like this it means you can directly compare the output of your translation and the output of the list comprehension. `mytokens` should be exactly the same as `my_list` if done correctly.

Also there is a small mistake in the second translation. It should be:

```
for word in mytokens:
    if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations:
        yield word
```

You could also modify this second translation to add all your words to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify this:

```
coll = ["Gerry", "Mary", "Sue"]

comprehended = [ word.lower() for word in coll]

def comprehender(coll):
  coll_out = []
  for word in coll:
      coll_out.append(word.lower())
  return coll_out
```

If you run this, you can be assured that the two are equivalent by using `assert` or just `return`ing `comprehended == comprehender(coll)`

This is a valid sanity check you can do on any list comprehension, you just vary this pattern to match the logic of your comprehension.

Comment: oh interesting! Thank you i will give this a shot